# How do I query workitems with the build number starts with 1.1

Tags: tfs, workitem

If I use build number contains = 1.1, it also returns all the work items for with build number  starts with 1.1 and also if 1.1 contains anywhere in build number. For example 1.0.1.123. Is there any way to use Regex or something similar to query work items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the default work item query can not achieve that. You can create the custom query using TFS API.